# Error while compliling DROP IF EXISTS , syntax error near table Android SQLite

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am trying to make a small program that contains two EditTexts for user to enter his name and his password and a button which adds them in a table using SQLite in Android,
but I got that message by my SQLException :

> **android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException:near "table":syntax error (code1):,while compiling: DROP TABLE IF EXISTS**

and in my logcat this line appear : (1) near "table" : syntax error

and I can't figure out where the problem

Here is my code :

```
package com.example.database;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DataBaseAdapter  {

Helper helper ;
public DataBaseAdapter(Context context){
    helper = new Helper ( context);
}
public long insertData (String name , String password)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contenValues = new ContentValues ();
    contenValues.put(Helper.NAME, name);
    contenValues.put(Helper.PASSWORD, password);
    long id = db.insert(Helper.TABEL_NAME, null, contenValues);
    return id ; 

}

static class Helper extends SQLiteOpenHelper  {
    private static final String DATABSE_NAME = "myDataBase";
    private static final String TABEL_NAME = "table";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 10;
    public static final String NAME = "Name";
    public static final String PASSWORD = "password";

    private static final String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE "+TABEL_NAME+" (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT , "+NAME+" TEXT not null , "+PASSWORD+" TEXT not null)";
    private Context context;
    private static final String DROP_TABLE = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABEL_NAME;


    public Helper(Context context) {

        super(context, DATABSE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.context = context;
        Message.message(context, "constructor called");

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        // CREATE DATABSE

        try {
            db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
            Message.message(context, "OnCreate called");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Message.message(context, "" + e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        try {
            db.execSQL(DROP_TABLE);
            Message.message(context, "onUpgrade called");

            onCreate(db);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Message.message(context, "" + e);
        }

    }
}

}
```

and in the **MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

EditText userName, password;

DataBaseAdapter helper;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    helper = new DataBaseAdapter(this);
    userName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.userText);
    password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passText);

}

public void addUser(View view) {

    String user = userName.getText().toString();
    String pass = password.getText().toString();

    long id = helper.insertData(user, pass);

    if ( id <0 )
    {
        Message.message(this, "fail");
    } else {
        Message.message(this, "Suceeded");

    }

}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't create (nor do any other operation) a table named... `table`, because `table` is a reserved word in SQLite (and in SQL in general).

Since the table is not created, it can't be deleted.

Try calling it `myTable` (or possibly a more significant name), such as the element name (normally, in its plural form: i.e.: Persons, Contacts, Animals, Orders, ...)

Comment: what a fatal mistake ! 
I have changed the name and it has worked 
Thanks alot Golem :)

Answer (score 0):

Try putting table in single quotes and using semicolon in the end of the statement, like this:

```
private static final String TABEL_NAME = "table";

private static final String DROP_TABLE = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS '" + TABEL_NAME + "';";
```

Comment: thanks for the reply 
but the problem was that I shouldn't name the table with " table " as it is a keyword 
thanks :)